# Is Absorption laws of sets suit here?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It is given, $A \subseteq B $ , Need to show that, $ A \cap B = A $.
What I have tried is,
from Absorption laws of sets $A = A \cup ( A \cap B ) $
and there after I have obtained the answer directly from the given relationship $A \subseteq B $.
I don't want the answer , what I want to know is whether my approach is correct or not. If wrong please give some hints.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I edited it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not seeing how you can draw the desired conclusion from the fact and hypothesis (directly). It may be possible, though. Can you spell out your approach?

Instead, note that we always have $A\cap B\subseteq A.$ Now, use the fact that $A\subseteq B$ to show that $A\subseteq A\cap B.$

Comment: Since $ A \subseteq B $ is given, I deduced the answer from the Absorption law. (The "Union" part will be same as $ A \cap B $)

Comment: Can you explain your approach bit further? :)

Comment: (Yes, but *why* is it the same as $A\cap B$?) If $x\in A,$ then since $A\subseteq B,$ what else do we know about $x$?